# Is it possible to cast UWP app to another display (like Screen casting)?

Tags: uwp, chromecast, screencast, miracast

In screen casting, entire screen will display in selected wireless display device.

My idea is to cast the app(UWP),instead of entire screen. i.e On clicking the 'cast' button in UWP application, the app will cast to selected **wireless display** device (it may be of another tablet/monitor).

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would use the ProjectionManager API.  Guidelines for using the API are [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn495078.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). and a sample is [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Projection).